# Why doesn't IE show file download dialog for PDF with GWT Window.open()?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt, window.open

We are generating PDF documents for our customers and serving them with a Servlet.
The following code works with Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but not with any version of IE. The popup window only flashes with IE but nothing happens. However, we can get the file download dialog to show by making a direct request to the servlet from the address bar in IE.
We've tried with several ContentTypes (application/download, application/x-download, etc.)

Client side code:

```
String URL = "/files/pdf?pdfId=" + getPdfId();
Window.open(URL, "_blank", "");
```

Servlet serving the pdf as byte[]:

```
byte[] bytes = getFileAsByteArray();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=document.pdf");
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
for (int length = 0; (length = in.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Content-Disposition: inline
```

instead of:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=document.pdf
```

Try this out, then tell something
Found that if I use inline then I should NOT use
filename=document.pdf, this will NOT work in IE.
(other browsers ignore it)

You can read it here: http://indiwiz.com/2009/03/11/forcing-http-download/

Comment: Well, this works, but shows the pdf inside the browser window instead of opening a download dialog. I'm specifically trying to find a way to open that download dialog.

Comment: I guess we can't find the proper solution so I'm going to accept this as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of pdf plugin problem.
[Link to adobe site for more details](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/328/328233.html)

Comment: Nope. We're not trying to show the pdf in browser. The goal is to show the user a file download dialog. The file should be downloadable regardless of any browser plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't solve a problem - try to change something inside your problem! Try to send ziped pdf-file or another content. It should help you to find  a root of trouble. If everything will work with zip file you don't need to send pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+URL,"","");
```

This might work !
I´m using :

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+URL, "", "");
```

and it's working just fine

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I'll try this, too.